# metafont crashes when using showit

Tags: metafont, miktex2.9

[Updated]

I am interested in using metafont, and working through the initial steps.
When I use the simple command *drawdot (35,70); showit;* a blank (white) window is opened with the title "METAFONT Screen (768 x 1024)", but then I get a window to say that metafont has reported that "a problem caused the program to stop working correctly" and it terminates.

Environment: Windows 10, METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit)
 
I invoke metafont with *mf --interaction=errorstopmode --screen*

The issue has been logged and acknowledged on github.

Geoffrey

Comment: meatfont can't make pdf (can it?) so it isn't clear why acrobat comes in to this. for me `drawdot (35,70); showit;` opens the metafont view window with a dot, but not all compilations of metafont include a viewer. I don't know what the miktex one uses.

Comment: Thanks David. I am assuming that the MiKTeX implementation creates a PDF and then invokes the system-defined viewer. I am not familiar with other implementations, so am not aware what other options they use for opening a view window on a Windows OS. I guess that since teh command window cannot display graphics there must be some implementation-defined way of executing the "showit" command.

Comment: On further investigation, I see that I was confusing my windows. The window that opens is labelled "METAFONT Screen" - nothing to do with PDF or Adobe Viewer. So the isue seens to be with the MiKTeX implementation. Apologies for my confusion!

Comment: Ah that sounds more reasonable, sorry I can't help with miktex. I suggest though you edit the question to correct the text and tag it with miktex so it's more likely to be seen and understood. (Not everyone looks at comments)

Comment: Here is the issue on Github: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/33